# What would be the value of msg.sender in a function called inside a contract constructor?

Tags: constructor, solidity, smartcontracts

I have read that during a contract deployment, inside the constructor, the contract address is not defined yet. So if this constructor was calling a function of another contract, what would this function get as the msg.sender ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tested my question on a virtual network and it seems that during the deployment of a contract, functions called inside the constructor will receive a different address than the final address after deployment, and this deployment address cannot be detected as a being a contract's address contrary to the final address.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is what is ran when the contract is launched on the blockchain. msg.sender is the variable pointer that is the wallet address that is launching or interacting with the contract.

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, during the execution of a constructor, the `msg.sender` variable holds the address of the account or contract that is deploying the contract.

Here's an example to illustrate:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
}
```

In this example, the constructor sets the `owner` variable to the address of the account or contract that deploys the `MyContract` contract. This will typically be the externally owned account (EOA) or the contract address that is creating the new instance of `MyContract`.